# Issue with *apply function in R

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr, apply

I hope you are able to direct me into the right direction. I very much believe that I am overthinking this.

In a nutshell, I have a list of data.frames split by country. Every `data.frame` has three columns: Country Name, Company Name, indicator for satisfaction.

I want to find the nth value of the company for every country. For example: Give me the 7th best company for every country based on satisfaction indicator. Preferably in a `data.frame` output with Country and company name.

First, I have cleaned the input `df`, checking for `NAs` and ordering from highest to lowest.

Then I have split the `df` based on Country.

```
group_by_country <- split.data.frame(ordered_needed_data, ordered_needed_data$Country)
>str(group_by_country)
List of 54
```

Since the input data is already ordered, I have thought that a simple 'helper' function would work

```
helperfunction <- function (x, rank) {
x[rank, 1:2]
}
```

If I apply now, this function to the input list, I retrieve the following error:

```
lapply(group_by_country, helperfunction, rank = 2)
Error in x[rank, 1:2]: incorrect number of dimensions.
```

I am not sure, how to interpret and how to fix this error. I would appreciate some help. Thanks !

Comment: It looks like your `group_by_country` object isn't what you think it is. Take a look at `str(group_by_country)`.  If it looks okay, edit (some of?) the result into your question and maybe we'll spot the issue.

Comment: Thank you. Apologies for not adding. It is a list of 54 elements. Every dataframe within the list has slightly different dimensions. Some have 17x3, some have 98x3.

Comment: If you look at `lapply(group_by_country, dim)` I think you will find that some items of your list do not have 2 dimensions, hence the error when you try to apply `helperfunction` which assumes (at least) 2 dimensions in the input.

Comment: Thank you. I have to be honest, I have not checked it, assuming that splitting it into a dataframe will create two dimensions. There are two lists which have a dim 1x3.

Comment: If all elements of the list are dataframes, it shouldn't matter than some of them have only one row.  However if you do something that converts some of them to matrices, your `helperfunction()` will make them into vectors; and if some of them don't have 2 columns, the same thing will happen.  Use `drop = FALSE` when indexing to prevent this.